# Remove rows with NA values and delete those observations in another year

Tags: r, dplyr

I find it a bit hard to find the right words for what I'm trying to do.

Say I have this dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

# A tibble: 74 x 3
       country  year conf_perc
         <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1      Canada  2017        77
 2      France  2017        45
 3     Germany  2017        60
 4      Greece  2017        33
 5     Hungary  2017        67
 6       Italy  2017        38
 7      Canada  2009        88
 8      France  2009        91
 9     Germany  2009        93
10      Greece  2009        NA
11     Hungary  2009        NA
12       Italy  2009        NA
```

Now I want to delete the rows that have `NA` values in 2009 but then I want to remove the rows of those countries in 2017 as well. I would like to get the following results:

```
# A tibble: 74 x 3
       country  year conf_perc
         <chr> <dbl>     <dbl>
 1      Canada  2017        77
 2      France  2017        45
 3     Germany  2017        60
 4      Canada  2009        88
 5      France  2009        91
 6     Germany  2009        93
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do `any` after grouping by 'country'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  filter(!any(is.na(conf_perc)))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   country [3]
#  country  year conf_perc
#    <chr> <int>     <int>
#1  Canada  2017        77
#2  France  2017        45
#3 Germany  2017        60
#4  Canada  2009        88
#5  France  2009        91
#6 Germany  2009        93
```

Answer (score 2):

`base` R solution:

```
foo <- df$year == 2009 & is.na(df$conf_perc) 
bar <- df$year == 2017 & df$country %in% unique(df$country[foo])
df[-c(which(foo), which(bar)), ]

#   country year conf_perc
# 1  Canada 2017        77
# 2  France 2017        45
# 3 Germany 2017        60
# 7  Canada 2009        88
# 8  France 2009        91
# 9 Germany 2009        93
```